# Setting random values from an Array into a List till condition is met. in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, random, while-loop

I want to set new random values from an Array into a List till one of two conditions is met. But it's only letting me add another 1 value without considering the condition. After I enter "y" the program letting me to get another value and then it asking me again if I want another card, when I enter "y" again , the code move on without letting me add another value. 
The second problem is with the if(Hands.playerHand.Sum() > 22) I want the program to calculate the total value of the list and if it's more then 22 then execute the command.

Thank you!

```
        string userAnotherCard = Console.ReadLine();

        bool secondHand = true;
        secondHand = (userAnotherCard == "y");

        bool secondHandNo = true;
        secondHandNo = (userAnotherCard == "n");

        while(secondHand)
        {

                //if user want another card, this programm will ganerate another card and store it inside playerHand

                    Hands.playerHand.Add(Deck.CardDeck[Hands.rando.Next(0, Deck.CardDeck.Length)]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Your cards are: ");
                    Hands.playerHand.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

                    Console.WriteLine("Would u like to take another card?");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                 if(Hands.playerHand.Sum() > 22)
                    Console.WriteLine("You loss, your cards sum is more than 21");
                    break;
        }

        while (secondHandNo)
                    break;
```

So I changed the code a little. Now I can choose as many values as I want but I have a problem with the while (secondHandNo) and the while (Hands.playerHand.Sum() > 21) commands. When I enter "n" *after taking another card* the while (secondHandNo) which should continue the code wont executed. The while (Hands.playerHand.Sum() > 21) doesn't executed as well. It's just giving me more values no matter what my answer is. Note that when I enter "n" right away without taking another card, the command work just fine and it's taking me to the rest of the code.

```
        string userAnotherCard = Console.ReadLine();

        bool secondHand = true;
        secondHand = (userAnotherCard == "y");

        bool secondHandNo = true;
        secondHandNo = (userAnotherCard == "n");

        while (secondHand)
        {

            Hands.playerHand.Add(Deck.CardDeck[Hands.rando.Next(0, Deck.CardDeck.Length)]);
            Console.WriteLine("Your cards are: ");
            Hands.playerHand.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

            Console.WriteLine("Would u like to take another card?");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
            while (Hands.playerHand.Sum() > 21)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You loss, your cards sum is more than 21");
                break;
            }


            while (secondHandNo)
                break;
```

Comment: Where do you store the user response to your request about a second card? The break inside the first while is always executed because is not inside a braces block { .... } after the Sum. And doing maths requires precision > 22 is 23

Comment: There is a lot of useless code here: f.i. while(secondhandno) break; A simple blank line will have the same effect

Comment: How can I store user response? I tried to create new bool varb with the value "y" again and compare it to user response (all this inside the while(secondHand){} ) but it wont work. Im really new into coding so I hope you can tip me on this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to fix this block of code. It seems to work now. I set the whole block into while loop and set each condition with an if statement and a break; if condition is met.

```
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Would u like to take another card?");
            string userAnotherCard = Console.ReadLine();

            bool secondHand = true;
            secondHand = (userAnotherCard == "y");

            bool secondHandNo = true;
            secondHandNo = (userAnotherCard == "n");

            if (secondHand)
            {
                Hands.playerHand.Add(Deck.CardDeck[Hands.rando.Next(0, Deck.CardDeck.Length)]);
                Console.WriteLine("Your cards are: ");
                Hands.playerHand.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

            }
            if (Hands.playerHand.Sum() > 21)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You loss, your cards sum is more than 21");
                break;
            }


            if (secondHandNo)
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few issues here:

1. You are not storing the result from the console. This can be solve easily:

   ```
   userAnotherCard = Console.ReadLine();
   ```
2. Even if we stored it, in the `while` your condition checks a value that was previously assigned and is never changed. This the reason that you are in an endless loop. I would replace it simply with the condition itself:

   ```
   while (userAnotherCard == "y")
   ```
3. It seems you are using `while break` instead of a simple `if`:

   ```
   if (Hands.playerHand.Sum() > 21)
   ```
4. `while (secondHandNo) break;` is useless and can be removed from the code.

That should be enough. Final code can look like this:

```
string userAnotherCard = Console.ReadLine();

while (userAnotherCard == "y")
{
    Hands.playerHand.Add(Deck.CardDeck[Hands.rando.Next(0, Deck.CardDeck.Length)]);
    Console.WriteLine("Your cards are: ");
    Hands.playerHand.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

    Console.WriteLine("Would u like to take another card?");
    userAnotherCard = Console.ReadLine();

    if (Hands.playerHand.Sum() > 21)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You loss, your cards sum is more than 21");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply . I changed the code . pls take a look and let me know your thoughts.!